# ArrayList 2D Clear Function Clears all

Tags: java, arraylist, 2d

This doesn't work:

```
public void Indexes() {
    for (int i=0;i<Names.size();i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<Mixed.size();j++) {
            if (Names.get(i).equals(Mixed.get(j))) {
                Index2.add(j);
            }
        }
        Index.add(Index2);
        Index2.clear();
    }
}
}
```

Everytime I clear it clears both of them... I worked on this for hours trying to get around it and failed, I also checked online but haven't found anything that work that I could understand, Can anyone help me?

Comment: "_Everytime I clear it clears both of them_"... Both the inner and outer arraylist?

Comment: Although this might not be the solution to your exact problem, try moving `Index.add(Index2);` and `Index2.clear();` out of the inner for loop, move it into the body of the outermost for loop. It's sorta more logical that way.